# How to get additional private consoles in LXC (not using host's TTYs)?

Tags: lxc

I created a LXC container, and I can connect to it's console 0
`lxc-console -n foo -t 0`

But I want more than one **virtual, private (container only)** console.

If I set `lxc.tty = 2` in the config, that refers to host TTY's that are supposed to be shared with the container, I don't want that.

The LXC manual offers `lxc.pts.max` however I tried adding that to my config file but `lxc-start` gave me a parse error saying there is no such key as `lxc.pts` or `lxc.pts.max`

My lxc-start is version 2.0.8 on Ubuntu 16.04.

Alternatively if it's not possible to get more than one virtual private container-only console, is it possible for me to run screen or tmux in the container?